# Adding vertical space between two \hline

Tags: tables, spacing

How can I add vertical space between the double line in the example below? I tried to use `\vspace`, but that results in a `Misplaced \noalign` error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            Test 1 & Blah \\
            \hline
            % <Add space here>
            \hline
            Test 2 & Blah \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setlength\doublerulesep{2cm}`

Comment: don't use `[h]` on its own (LaTeX usually warns about that) use `[htp]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space is controlled by the parameter `\doublerulesep` which you can set at any point in the document

```
\setlength\doublerulesep{2cm}
```

Either in the preamble for the whole document or if just this table, inside the `table` environment alongside `\centering` and any other local declarations.

Answer (score 4):

Another straightforward 'duh' way of doing this; hacky, but it works, and you have complete control over individual double hline segments without having to mess with any other environments or variables:

```
\hline  
\multicolumn{15}{c}{}\\[-0.5em]
\hline
```

Adapt this for the particular number of columns in your table (in this case `15`), and particular interval you desire between hlines (in this case `-0.5em`)